# A vector that is in the subspace but not column space?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

So, first I will explain a scenario, then give you my understanding, and then ask the question.

**Scenario:**
Let's say we have the equation Ax = b , where A is a m*n matrix, x is a n *1 column vector, and b is the constant vector, and we are dealing with an overdetermined system (we have way more rows than columns..1,000,000 rows and 30 columns, let's say)

**My understanding:**
The odds that the b vector is in the column space of A is close to 0. By not being in the column space of A, we mean that the odds that b is a linear combination of the columns of A is close to 0.

**Question**
If *my understanding* is true, how is it then that vector b is said to be in the SAME subspace as the Columns of A?

Comment: Once you have $Ax=b$, you automatically have that $b$ is in the column space of $A$. 100% guaranteed. This pretty much follows immediately from the definition of "column space", since $Ax=b$ implies that $b$ can be written as a linear combination of the columns of $A$.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow that is just not true.

Comment: Of course it is true. That's exactly what $Ax = b$ means.

Comment: @Bungo How would you know ahead of time if there is a solution for x? lol

Comment: If $x$ is not a solution, then $Ax$ does not equal $b$.

Comment: @ed8484 if you're given that $Ax=b$ then you know $b$ is a solution. You gave us this information when you stated the problem.

Comment: So how would you present this equation when you're in the process of figuring out if there is a solution for x?

Comment: @ed8484 One way to make this clear would be "Let's say we are trying to determine whether $Ax = b$ has a solution..." vs. "Let's say we have the equation $Ax = b$..." But I think the main reason for people's confusion was when you asked "how is it then that the vector $b$ is said to be in the same subspace as the columns of $A$?" - I think we all thought you meant the column space of $A$. But of course $b$ *isn't* in the column space of $A$ unless $Ax = b$ has a solution.

Answer (score 2):

$b$ is in the column space of $A$ if and only if there is a solution $x$.

If there is no $x$ such $Ax = b$ then $b$ is not in the column space of $A$. It is however in the same vector space, namely $\mathbb R^m$, if you are working in $\mathbb R$.

The vector space $\mathbb R^m$ has many subspaces, including itself, not just the column space $C(A) = \{Ax |x\in R^n\}$.

Comment: So in the case of no solution for x, is b in the same subspace as the Column Space in the trivial sense? (i.e., the subspace as the whole vector space)?

Comment: @ed8484 If there is no solution, then $b$ is not in the column space in any sense. It is in $\mathbb R^m \setminus \text{col}(A)$ (i.e. it is in the set-theoretic complement of the column space).

Comment: Let me reword. If the Columns of A are embedded in Rm, how is it that b is also  embedded in that subspace? (in the scenario where there no solution to x)

Comment: $\mathbb R^m$ is its own subspace. $\mathbb R^m$ is a 'subspace' that contains both $b$ and the column space. There might be others, though.

Comment: @ed8484 Any vector with $m$ entries is an element of $\mathbb R^m$. The columns of $A$ have $m$ entries, and so does $b$, so they all live in $\mathbb R^m$.

Comment: @Bungo Ah. Thank you. That clears it up.